# Which motor is suitable for a sun tracker one axis?

Tags: solar-cell

Which motor is suitable for a sun tracker one axis and two axes and one of the specifications of this motor has high torque?

Answer (score 1):

Almost anything will do. You just put a big reduction gear on it. The higher the gear ratio, the greater the torque. The biggest limitation is the need to swing the array from the sunset back to the sunrise position.

Comment: Why is it a limitation?  It that because it requires a way to reverse the motor?

Comment: No, it's just that the slower the panel's movement, the longer you'll have to drive it to get it back to the starting point.

Comment: Which best method for tracking by a light sensor or by time?

Comment: Generally, tracking by time is adequate, since an error of a few degrees is unnoticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Any motor is fine. You have to choose according to what is easiest to control for you. If you have stepper controller, take stepper. If you have servo drive, take it. Mechanics is bigger issue information your case. You have to use one way gears.

Comment: Which best method for tracking by a light sensor or by time?

Comment: Define best... It depends on how accurate the mechanics is, how easily can you program the math... Assuming you don't have very accurate mechanics or a way to calibrate it, it's better to work in cosed loop. There is a common four sensors structure, like that:http://cdn.instructables.com/FBN/N0RK/GPBD4JQV/FBNN0RKGPBD4JQV.LARGE.jpg. Problem is that in clowdy weather the system may go to wrong direction, and also in the morning you will have to start from know position, so the system will always be able to find the sun.